# remove part of the segment from url laravel

Tags: php, url, laravel

I have a url like this:

```
http://example.com/en/search
```

Now I want to check the first segment of the url like

```
$lang = Request::segment(1);
```

And I want to remove the $lang segment if it matches to the certain conditions. I'm retieving the url like this

```
$url = Request::fullUrl();
```

Now I want to reconstruct the url to something like this

```
http://example.com/search
```

Please note I cannot use str_replace because it searches in all parts of the url, I just want to search and replace in the first segment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to make a quick check, then remove the first segment and redirect the user, you could easily do e.g. like this (for Laravel 5):

```
$segments = Request::segments();
$first = array_shift($segments);
if (some_condition) {
    return redirect()->to(implode('/', $segments));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
$str = 'http://example.com/en/search';
$part = explode('/',$str,5);

if ($part[3] == 'en') {
    $url = $part[0].'//'.$part[2].'/'.$part[4];
} else { 
    $url = $str;
}

echo '$url:['.$url.']';  // http://example.com/search
```